# How do I inline fields when marshalling JSON?

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I have a type `MonthYear` defined like

```
type MonthYear time.Time

func (my *MonthYear) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    t := time.Time(*my)

    return json.Marshal(&struct {
        Month int `json:"month"`
        Year  int `json:"year"`
    }{
        Month: int(t.Month()) - 1,
        Year:  t.Year(),
    })
}
```

I'm including it a lot of different structs like

```
type Event struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Date MonthYear
}

type Item struct {
    Category string `json:"category"`
    Date     MonthYear
}
```

How do I inline the `MonthYear` type so that the resulting JSON does not have any embedded objects?

I want the result to look like `{ "name": "party", "month": 2, "year": 2017 }` and `{ "category": "art", "month": 3, "year": 2016 }` without having to write the MarshalJSON for each of the structs.

Comment: If an answer by Brad Fitzpatrick is not enough for you, I don’t know what is. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6213

Comment: Also if you super want to you can use go generate to write the Marshall JSON functions

Answer (score 6):

I know this is not the answer you wish to receive, but until inline support is added to the [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package, you may use the following workaround:

Make your `MonthYear` a struct, e.g.:

```
type MonthYear struct {
    t     time.Time
    Month int `json:"month"`
    Year  int `json:"year"`
}
```

An optional, constructor function for easy creation:

```
func NewMonthYear(t time.Time) MonthYear {
    return MonthYear{
        t:     t,
        Month: int(t.Month()) - 1,
        Year:  t.Year(),
    }
}
```

And use [embedding](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) (anonymous field) instead of a regular (named) field to get "flattened" / inlined in the JSON representation:

```
type Event struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    MonthYear
}

type Item struct {
    Category string `json:"category"`
    MonthYear
}
```

As an extra, you'll be able to refer to fields directly like `Event.Year` or `Event.Month` which is nice.

Testing it:

```
evt := Event{Name: "party", MonthYear: NewMonthYear(time.Now())}
fmt.Println(json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(evt), evt.Year)

itm := Item{Category: "Tool", MonthYear: NewMonthYear(time.Now())}
fmt.Println(json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(itm))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ud7gLnrdmz)):

```
{"name":"party","month":10,"year":2009}
<nil> 2009
{"category":"Tool","month":10,"year":2009}
<nil>
```

Note: The `MonthYear.t` time field does not play a role here (it is not marshaled either). You can remove it if the original `time.Time` is not needed.